# grep regex 2nd word of each line and replace

Tags: bash

I have a file with 2 columns:

```
user1 password1
user2 password2
...
```

users and passwords are separated by a tabulation, the next user is in the next line.

I would like to retrieve the password of each user and replace it by its md5 hash.

I know that this regex can get the tabulation+the password but I don't know how to capture it in a variable so I can remove the tabulation and work on my password string.

```
\t(.*)$
```

So atm my code looks like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]
do
  if [[ $p =~ (\t)(.*)$]]; then echo yep ; else echo nope; fi
done < $1
```

Comment: This might help: `while IFS='$\n' read -r user pass; do echo "$user $pass"; done < file`

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696722/awk-and-md5-replace-a-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it in shell:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

while read -r user passwd; do 
  md5passwd=$(printf %s "$passwd" | md5sum | cut -c-32)
  printf '%s\t%s\n' "$user" "$md5passwd"
done
```

Or using word splitting into arguments rather than `cut`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

while read -r u p; do 
  # shellcheck disable=SC2046 # intended word splitting
  set -- $(printf %s "$p" | md5sum )
  printf '%s\t%s\n' "$u" "$1"
done
```

While md5 of password looks less insecure than plaintext password. You must not ignore that md5 password hashing is dramatically weak. You really must not roll your own cryptography.

I mean **Really! Do not do that!**