# Hash a CSV Column data on linux server

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a CSV text file with a header row.

The file looks like this:

```
COLUMN1|COLUMN2|COLUMN3|COLUMN4|...|
Field1|Field2|Field3|Field4|...|
...
```

I need to obscure the data in (for example) columns 2, without affecting any of the other entries in the file.

I want to do this using a hashing algorithm like SHA1 or MD5, so that the same strings will resolve to the same hash values anywhere they are encountered. Any inputs on how to do using shell scripting in linux. I tried searching through and found out ways to do in powershell, Python.

Any inputs are much appreciated!
Thanks for your time!!

Comment: See: [awk and md5: replace a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23696722/3776858) or [Awk replace a column with its hash value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8024392/3776858)

Comment: Is there some other way we can do instead of using MD5, so that we should be able to decrypt the encrypted field

Comment: The goal of a hash algorithm (here md5) is to make the process as non-reversible as possible. This might help: [Symmetric-key algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a language installed that has both CSV and Digest modules. Perhaps `ruby`:

```sh
ruby -rdigest -rcsv -e '
    encoder = Digest::SHA1.new
    output = CSV.new($stdout, col_sep: "|")
    nr = 0
    CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift, col_sep: "|") do |row|
        nr += 1
        row[1] = encoder.hexdigest(row[1]) if nr > 1
        output << row
    end
' file
```

Otherwise, with bash, it'll be slower, and the CSV parsing doesn't cover the CSV edge cases

```sh
declare -A hashes
{
    IFS= read -r header
    echo "$header"
    while IFS='|' read -ra fields; do
        value=${fields[1]}
        if [[ -z ${hashes[$value]} ]]; then
            hashes[$value]=$(printf '%s' "$value" | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
        fi
        fields[1]=${hashes[$value]}
        (IFS='|'; echo "${fields[*]}")
    done
} < file
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time in responding. Your code did work and I also used awk and also perl which also worked!!

Comment: Found out that hash cannot be reversed. is there some other way to encrypt and then decrypt the same field at later time.

Comment: The idea behind checksums is that you'll take two unencrypted strings, get the checksum for each, and see if they're equal. So you don't "un-checksum" and see if that's equal to the 2nd plaintext string. This is why password checksums, not plaintext passwords or obfuscated passwords,  are stored in the database: you don't want hackers to be able to decrypt users' passwords.

Comment: That being said, this has become an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info): what are you really trying to do? Forget about MD5 or SHA, what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I have a CSV File which has a column that cannot be seen in local file system when an output is created from an ETL process. After that, when the same file is sent to downstream application, it has to decrypt and process that value. So, my goal is is to encrypt and pass along the details of how to decrypt to downstream app. I have mistakenly given the title has hash instead of Encrypt

Comment: How secure does the encrypting need to be? is `base64` sufficient? If the data is that sensitive, then you should not be writing to the filesystem, you should be using an encrypted transport protocol

Comment: I have a before job subroutine which can call a script and encrypt only that field before writing to the file system. So, i am trying to find out if that is possible using scripting. Thank you so much for taking time to respond to my questions!!